# Inequality $n^{\sqrt{n+2}}>(n+1)^{\sqrt{n+1}}$ solution

Tags: inequality

How to find the solution of inequality 
$$n^{\sqrt{n+2}}>(n+1)^{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
for integers with basic analysis without derivatives.

I don't have any idea how to start with it.

Comment: This is not true for $n=1$

Comment: @Bo5man I'm looking for the integer from  what it's true

Comment: From the statement I could not interpret that. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the smallest $n$ such that

$$\frac{n^{\sqrt{n+2}}}{(n+1)^{\sqrt{n+1}}} > 1$$ Take logarithms and search for the zero of 
$$g(n)=\sqrt{n+2} \log (n)-\sqrt{n+1} \log (n+1)$$ Assume that $n$ is large and use
$$\sqrt{n+2}\sim \sqrt n+\frac 1 { \sqrt n}$$ 
$$\sqrt{n+1}\sim \sqrt n+\frac 1 {2 \sqrt n}$$ 
$$\log(n+1)=\log(n)+\log\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)\sim \log(n)+\frac 1 n$$ Replace to get
$$g(n) \sim  -\frac{1}{2n^{3/2}} (2 n-n \log (n)+1)$$
The solution of $2 n-n \log (n)+1=0$ is given in terms of Lambert function; so, the approximation is 
$$n =\frac{1}{W\left(\frac{1}{e^2}\right)}$$ Since the argument is small, use $W(x)\approx \frac{x}{x+1}$ which makes $\color{red}{n=1+e^2 \approx 8.39}$ while the exact solution of $g(n)=0$ in the real domain would be $8.70$. Then $\color{red}{n=9}$.

Let us check the values of  $$f(n)=n^{\sqrt{n+2}}-(n+1)^{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
$$f(8)=8^{\sqrt{10}}-729 \approx -11.50 \qquad f(9)=9^{\sqrt{11}}-10^{\sqrt{10}}\approx 8.68$$