# Can equivalents be "better" than series?

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion, approximation

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045728/inequality-n-sqrtn2n1-sqrtn1-solution/3046239#3046239), the asker specified *without derivatives* and I provided an answer using the most basic equivalents which gives me a quite accurate result.

Later, I made the problem more general
$$n^{\sqrt{n+a}}>(n+b)^{\sqrt{n+b}}\implies n > \,\, ??? $$ 
and looked (as explained in my answer) for an estimate , in the real domain, of the zero of 
$$g(n)=\sqrt{n+a} \log (n)-\sqrt{n+b} \log (n+b) \tag 1$$ Assuming that the solution could be large, I used to most basic equivalents
$$\sqrt{n+k}\sim \sqrt n+\frac k {2 \sqrt n}\qquad \text{and} \qquad \log(n+k)\sim \log(n)+\frac k n$$
Doing it, I arrive to the problem of solving for $n$
$$n (a-b) \log (n)-2bn -b^2=0$$
the solution of which (if it exists) being
$$n_{(1)}=\frac{b^2}{(a-b)\, W\left(\frac{b^2 }{a-b}e^{-\frac{2 b}{a-b}}\right)}$$ which, assuming that the argument of Lambert function is small, can be approximated as 
$$n_{(2)}=\frac{b^2}{a-b}+e^{\frac{2 b}{a-b}}$$ Now, the problem is that, using series
$$g(n)=\frac{(a-b) \log (n)-2 b}{2 \sqrt{n}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ giving
$$n_{(3)}=e^{\frac{2 b}{a-b}}$$

The problem, and then my question (and my surprise), is that $n_{(1)}$ and $n_{(2)}$ are much better than $n_{(3)}$. I give in text table some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 a & b & n_{(1)} & n_{(2)} & n_{(3)} & \text{solution} \\
 2 & 1 & 8.33137 & 8.38906 & 7.38906 & 8.70391 \\
 3 & 2 & 58.4644 & 58.5982 & 54.5982 & 59.3338 \\
 4 & 3 & 412.331 & 412.429 & 403.429 & 413.769 \\
 5 & 4 & 2996.92 & 2996.96 & 2980.96 & 2998.90  \\
 6 & 5 & 22051.5 & 22051.5 & 22026.5 & 22053.9 \\
 7 & 6 & 162791. & 162791. & 162755. & 162794. \\
   &   &         &         &         & \\ 
 3 & 1 & 3.18097 & 3.21828 & 2.71828 & 3.47785 \\
 4 & 2 & 9.18632 & 9.38906 & 7.38906 & 9.78682 \\
 5 & 3 & 24.1918 & 24.5855 & 20.0855 & 25.2064 \\
 6 & 4 & 62.1043 & 62.5982 & 54.5982 & 63.6493  \\
 7 & 5 & 160.439 & 160.913 & 148.413 & 162.586 \\
 8 & 6 & 421.049 & 421.429 & 403.429 & 423.813 \\
   &   &         &         &         & \\ 
 4 & 1 & 2.25763 & 2.28107 & 1.94773 & 2.52323 \\
 5 & 2 & 4.96291 & 5.12700 & 3.79367 & 5.45027 \\
 6 & 3 & 9.98014 & 10.3891 & 7.38906 & 10.7364 \\
 7 & 4 & 19.0435 & 19.7252 & 14.3919 & 20.1512 \\
 8 & 5 & 35.4581 & 36.3650 & 28.0316 & 37.0121 \\
 9 & 6 & 65.564 & 66.5982 & 54.5982 & 67.6543
\end{array}
\right)$$

> I wonder if I am making a mistake somewhere. Comments and suggestions will really be welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For n1 calculation, the equivalents correspond to a serie approximation with an error in $n^{-2}$. I guess you saw it of course

Answer (score 1):

We obtained the following approximate equations for $n$:

> $n (a-b) \log (n)-2bn -b^2=0$
>
> $\frac{(a-b) \log (n)-2 b}{2 \sqrt{n}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)=0$

But it turned out that when we take more precise equivalents we obtain a different equation. Namely, we have

$$\sqrt{n+k} \sim n^{1/2}+\frac 12kn^{-1/2}-\frac 18k^2n^{-3/2},$$

$$\log (n+k)\sim\log n+kn^{-1}-\frac 12k^2n^{-2}.$$

Then

$$g(n)\sim\left(n^{1/2}+\frac 12an^{-1/2}-\frac 18a^2n^{-3/2}\right)\log n-
\left(n^{1/2}+\frac 12bn^{-1/2}-\frac 18b^2n^{-3/2}\right)
\left(\log n+bn^{-1}-\frac 12b^2n^{-2}\right)\sim$$
$$\frac 12(a-b)n^{-1/2}\log n-bn^{-1/2}-\frac 18(a^2-b^2)n^{-3/2}\log n+ O(n^{-5/2}\log n).$$

Comment: Yes, I know. The problem is that, if I expand the Taylor series for the next term, I cannot solve the equation anymore. I understand that the equivalent are a bit more precise than the first term. What is also amazing if that $n_{(2)}$ derived from an approximation of $n_{(1)}$ is better then $n_{(1)}$ itself ! Thnaks for answering. Cheers.